# Would the magnetic north affect magnetic railways?

Tags: magnetic-fields

Just a theoretical question, but let's assume that a magnetic railway was built in the magnetic north. Would it be affected in any way? Would the earth's natural magnetic pole disrupt the maglev's magnetic field?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I honestly don't know in the slightest, which is precisely why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(magnetic_field) the magnetic field of earth is on the order of 50 microtesla on the surface, I would assume that it is irrelevant given the strength of the maglev field.

http://www.supraconductivite.fr/en/index.php?p=applications-trains-maglev-more

Here it states that the field of a maglev goes up to 5 Tesla, which is 5 orders of magnitude stronger than earth's magnetic field. Earth's magnetic field can therefore be neglected.